# Citation Generator functionality of tabs doesn't work as desired

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

### Current Issues:

1-By Default the First Main Tab with data-tab="1" and First Sub Tab with the data-tab="1" and the Inputs related to First Sub Tab with the data-tab="1" are active thats good to go.
But when click on other sub-tab with data-tab="1" it does not remove the active-sub-tab class from all the tabs and add to clicked one. Which keeps adding the active-sub-tab on all the tabs thats the huge issue.
2- If I click on other main tabs it by default shows the first sub tab as active but does not show its respective inputs

My part of HTML structure

```
<div id="main-tabs">
    <button class="tab active" onclick="showTab('book')" data-tab="1">
        Book
    </button>
    <button class="tab" onclick="showTab('book-section')" data-tab="2">
        Book Section
    </button>
    <button class="tab" onclick="showTab('journal')" data-tab="3">
        Journal
    </button>
    <button class="tab" onclick="showTab('periodical')" data-tab="4">
        Periodical
    </button>
    <button class="tab" onclick="showTab('website')" data-tab="5">
        Website
    </button>
</div>
<div id="book" class="sub-tabs">
    <div class="sub-tabs-wrapper">
        <button class="sub-tab" onclick="showCitationStyle('apa-book')" data-tab="1"><span>APA</span><span>(Sixth Edition)</span></button>
        <button class="sub-tab" onclick="showCitationStyle('chicago-book')" data-tab="1"><span>Chicago</span><span>(Sixteenth Edition)</span></button>
        <button class="sub-tab" onclick="showCitationStyle('harvard-book')" data-tab="1"><span>Harvard</span><span>Anglia (2008)</span></button>
        <button class="sub-tab" onclick="showCitationStyle('ieee-book')" data-tab="1"><span>IEEE</span><span>(2006)</span></button>
        <button class="sub-tab" onclick="showCitationStyle('mla-book')" data-tab="1"><span>MLA</span><span>(Seventh Edition)</span></button>
        <button class="sub-tab" onclick="showCitationStyle('turabian-book')" data-tab="1"><span>Turabian</span><span>(Sixth Edition)</span></button>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="book-section" class="sub-tabs">
    <div class="sub-tabs-wrapper">
        <!-- 6 buttons with class sub-tab, same onclickCitationStyle() by replacing book with bookSection data-tab="2" -->
    </div>
</div>
<div id="journal" class="sub-tabs">
    <div class="sub-tabs-wrapper">
        <!-- 6 buttons with class sub-tab, same onclickCitationStyle() by replacing book with journal data-tab="3" -->
    </div>
</div>
<div id="periodical" class="sub-tabs">
    <div class="sub-tabs-wrapper">
        <!-- 6 buttons with class sub-tab, same onclickCitationStyle() by replacing book with periodical data-tab="4" -->
    </div>
</div>
<div id="website" class="sub-tabs">
    <!-- 6 buttons with class sub-tab, same onclickCitationStyle() by replacing book with website data-tab="5" -->
</div>
<!-- Inputs for Book Main tab -> sub-tabs -->
<div class="book-input-wrapper">
    <div id="apa-book" class="citation-style">
        <div class="cite-wrapper">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <!-- all the inputs for Book main tab sub-tab APA its generate button and output div -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="chicago-book" class="citation-style">
        <div class="cite-wrapper">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <!-- all the inputs for Book main tab sub-tab chicago its generate button and output div -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="harvard-book" class="citation-style">
        <div class="cite-wrapper">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <!-- all the inputs for Book main tab sub-tab harvard its generate button and output div -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ieee-book" class="citation-style">
        <div class="cite-wrapper">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <!-- all the inputs for Book main tab sub-tab ieee its generate button and output div -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mla-book" class="citation-style">
        <div class="cite-wrapper">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <!-- all the inputs for Book main tab sub-tab mla its generate button and output div -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="turabian-book" class="citation-style">
        <div class="cite-wrapper">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <!-- all the inputs for Book main tab sub-tab turabian its generate button and output div -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Inputs for Book Section Main tab -> sub-tabs -->
<div class="bookSection-input-wrapper">
    <!-- follow same structure as Inputs for Book Main tab -> sub-tabs just changed the ids by replacing -book from id to -bookSection -->
</div>
<!-- Inputs for Journal Main tab -> sub-tabs -->
<div class="journal-input-wrapper">
    <!-- follow same structure as Inputs for Book Main tab -> sub-tabs just changed the ids by replacing -book from id to -jouranl -->
</div>
<!-- Inputs for Journal Main tab -> sub-tabs -->
<div class="periodical-input-wrapper">
    <!-- follow same structure as Inputs for Book Main tab -> sub-tabs just changed the ids by replacing -book from id to -periodical -->
</div>
<!-- Inputs for Website Main tab -> sub-tabs -->
<div class="website-input-wrapper">
    <!-- follow same structure as Inputs for Book Main tab -> sub-tabs just changed the ids by replacing -book from id to -website -->
</div>
```

My part of JavaScript that have issues:

```
//Function to show the sub-tabs for a given main tab
function showTab(tabId) {
  // Hide all sub-tabs
  var subTabs = document.getElementsByClassName("sub-tabs");
  for (var i = 0; i < subTabs.length; i++) {
    subTabs[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Show the sub-tabs for the selected main tab
  document.getElementById(tabId).style.display = "block";
}

// Function to show the citation style inputs for a given citation style
function showCitationStyle(citationStyle) {
  // Hide all citation style inputs
  var citationStyles = document.getElementsByClassName("citation-style");
  for (var i = 0; i < citationStyles.length; i++) {
    citationStyles[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Show the citation style inputs for the selected citation style
  document.getElementById(citationStyle).style.display = "block";
}

// Get all the main tabs
var tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');

// Add the active class to the first tab
tabs[0].classList.add('active-tab');

for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
  tabs[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      // Remove the active class from all tabs
      for (var j = 0; j < tabs.length; j++) {
          tabs[j].classList.remove("active-tab");
      }
      // Add the active class to the clicked tab
      this.classList.add("active-tab");
  });
}  
// Get all the sub-tabs
var subTabs = document.querySelectorAll('.sub-tab');

// Add the active class to the first sub-tab
subTabs[0].classList.add('active-sub-tab');

for (var i = 0; i < subTabs.length; i++) {
subTabs[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Remove the active class from all sub-tabs
    for (var j = 0; j < subTabs.length; j++) {
        subTabs[j].classList.remove("active-sub-tab");
    }
    // Add the active class to the clicked sub-tab
    this.classList.add("active-sub-tab");
});
}
```

### Desired Output:

I want smooth tab functionality for Main Tab their sub tabs and respective inputs: in tabs and sub tabs I used data-tab for 5 main tabs. For each main tab there are 6 sub tabs defining which sub tabs are for which main tab by mentioning the same data-tab attribute in sub tabs
1- On Page Load - First Main Tab with data-tab="1" and its First sub-tab with data-tab="1" and its respective input should be active.
2- On click on other sub-tabs with data-tab="1" it should first remove the active-sub-tab class from all the sub-tab with data-tab="1" and add active-sub-tab class to clicked sub-tab with data-tab="1" and on every click on any sub-tab with data-tab="1" should display its respective inputs.
3- On Click on other main tab it should follow the same functionality with their respective data-tab attributes, sub-tab and respective inputs.

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [bad practice](/q/11737873/4642212). They’re an [obsolete, cumbersome, and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way to listen for events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Comment: `data-tab` attributes of the buttons are all having the same value `1`. You could also [delegate the events](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5Dwhat+is+event+delegation), that would make handling of dynamic content much easier, and reduce memory print of the code (you're creating a ton of unneeded functions in the loops). Then store the clicked button and tab into variables, that way you can use the stored reference to toggle its state, iterating the entire document on every click just wastes resources.